# How to remove first and last n characters from each line of a file

Tags: python, python-3.x

**Question**: How can we strip first 2 and last 2 characters of each line of a data file?

Want to remove first and last 2 characters from each line of a large data file. My following `python 3.x` code does remove first and last 2 characters from each file, but it writes all lines in one line to an output file. Following is a sample:

**Input File**:

```
This is a test for first line
This is a test for second line
This is a test for third line
This is a test for fourth line
```

**Expected Outpu file**:

```
is is a test for first li
is is a test for second li
is is a test for third li
is is a test for fourth li
```

**Code returns the following in Output file**:

```
is is a test for first linis is a test for second linis is a test for third linis is a test for fourth lin
```

**Code**:

```
with open('Test.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as inFile,\
     open('TestOUT.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as outFile:
    for line in inFile:
        outFile.write(line[2:-2])
```

Answer (score 2):

Missing newline after each line:

```py
for line in inFile:
    outFile.write(line[2:-2])
    outFile.write('\n')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can replace

```
        outFile.write(line[2:-2])
```

with

```
        print(line[2:-2], file=outFile)
```

Although as in your own code, that removes each line's suffix `'e\n'`, not `'ne\n'`. You'll have to choose how to fix that (probably slice more or rstrip first).